# How to get date of last september dynamically with moment.js

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, ionic3, angular2-moment

I need the date of last September with moment.js - but dynamically.

**Current Date**

`currentDate:string = moment().format('YYYY-MM'); // This will be 2017-10`

How to know when the last september was from the current date? I need somethink like this:

`lastSteptember = moment(this.currentDate).getDateOfLast('september').format('YYYY-MM');`

**So the result from now would be:**

`2017-09`

**But 3 months ago** the result would have been **another:**

`2016-09`

How do I can handle this with moment.js?

Comment: Is [`month()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) what you are looking for? I did not fully understand what you are trying to do. What did you try by yourself so far?

Comment: `month()` gives me the current month. But I need the last september as result. I am writing an application in which one year starts in September and ends in September. Therefore to get specific data, I need to know from the current month which year was last September.

Comment: `month(8)` and `month('September')` also works as a setter, if you want to customize moment behaviour see [Customize](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/) section of the docs.

Comment: In order to help readers please mark the answer for your problem.

Comment: I can´t mark the solution I have implemented until two days from now, because it is my own answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found a pretty solution and solved it like this:**

```
currentYear: number = moment().year();
lastYear: number = moment().subtract(1, 'years').year();
nextYear: number = moment().add(1, 'years').year();

if(moment().isSameOrAfter(this.currentYear + '-09-01', 'month')) {
  this.currentServiceYearStartDate = this.currentYear + '-09-01';
  this.currentServiceYearEndDate = this.nextYear + '-08-31';
} else {
  this.currentServiceYearStartDate = this.lastYear + '-09-01';
  this.currentServiceYearEndDate = this.currentYear + '-08-31';
}

console.log('Startdate: ' + this.currentServiceYearStartDate);
console.log('Enddate: ' + this.currentServiceYearEndDate);
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to make it work with moment. But you can use my function to get last month by month number:

```
var getLastMonth = function(month){
        if(month<1 || month>12) return undefined;
        let year = (month<=moment().month())? (moment().year()) : (moment().year()-1);
        return moment(month + "-" + year, "MM-YYYY");
}
```

Use it:

```
getLastMonth(11); //return 11-2016

getLastMonth(10); //return 10-2017

getLastMonth(9); //return 09-2017
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will return the month of the previous year if the given month is lower than the current month, otherwise it will return the month with the current year.

```
  function getMonthWithPresentOrPastYear(month, format) {
      currentMonth = parseInt(moment().format('M'));
      givenMonth = parseInt(moment().month(month).format('M'));
      format = format || 'YYYY-MM';

      return (givenMonth >= currentMonth) ?
        moment().month(month).format(format) : //  Present
        moment().month(month).subtract(1, 'year').format(format); // Past
    };

    getMonthWithPresentOrPastYear('January'); // returns '2016-01'
    getMonthWithPresentOrPastYear('September'); // returns '2016-09'
    getMonthWithPresentOrPastYear('October'); // returns '2017-10'
    getMonthWithPresentOrPastYear('December', 'YYYY/DD'); // returns '2017/12'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(moment()).getLast = function(month,format="YYYY-MM"){
 var date;
 if(this.diff("01 "+month+" "+this.year()) >= 0 || this.format("MMMM").toLowerCase() === month.toLowerCase)
    date = moment(this).month(month);
  else
    date = moment(this).month(month).subtract(1,"years");
 return date.format(format);
});
```

In the above JavaScript we check whether the month has passed in the current moment object.

This allows us to directly check from any moment object and of any month eg:

```
var customDate = moment("01 December 2001");
customDate.getLast("September"); //"2001-09"
```